# C Undefined Reference - Not Name Mangling

Tags: c, compilation, linker, opencl

All I have a project with source files (each func also has a .h):

- test_functions.c

  - func1.c
  - func2.c
  - func3.c
  - func4.c
  - func5.c

I am getting an undefined reference in `test_functions.c` for a function defined in `func3.c`.

Steps so far:

- `make VERBOSE=1` shows building func3.c and linking of func3.c.o
- `nm func3.c.o` shows symbol is defined
- `readelf -s func3.c.o` show symbol is defined as well
- `make VERBOSE=1` shows gcc is being used, not a name mangling issue

Here's where it gets interesting, I went wild and removed `func3.c` recompiled, and now i get and undefined reference to `func3` (obviously) and now also an undefined reference to `func2`!! Yet I've already compiled earlier with that function!

If I add `func3.c` back to the sources, comment out the function call to `func3()` I can call `func2()` just fine... I'm at a total loss.

---

Requested compile out:

```
Scanning dependencies of target test_opencl_functions
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/constantin/workspace/durp/tests/release_arm'
make -f CMakeFiles/test_opencl_functions.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/test_opencl_functions.dir/build
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/constantin/workspace/durp/tests/release_arm'
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/constantin/workspace/durp/tests/release_arm/CMakeFiles 14
[ 53%] Building C object CMakeFiles/test_opencl_functions.dir/src/opencl/opencl_functions/openclpyramid.c.o
/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc-4.5   -mthumb -fdata-sections -Wa,--noexecstack -fsigned-char -Wno-psabi -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -mthumb -fdata-sections -Wa,--noexecstack -fsigned-char -Wno-psabi -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -I/home/constantin/workspace/durp/tests/../PanasonicCameraLib -I/home/constantin/workspace/durp/tests/../linux_arm_tool/include    -o CMakeFiles/test_opencl_functions.dir/src/opencl/opencl_functions/openclpyramid.c.o   -c /home/constantin/workspace/durp/tests/src/opencl/opencl_functions/openclpyramid.c
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/constantin/workspace/durp/tests/release_arm/CMakeFiles 15
[ 57%] Building C object CMakeFiles/test_opencl_functions.dir/src/opencl/opencl_functions/openclimagewarp.c.o
/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc-4.5   -mthumb -fdata-sections -Wa,--noexecstack -fsigned-char -Wno-psabi -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -mthumb -fdata-sections -Wa,--noexecstack -fsigned-char -Wno-psabi -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -I/home/constantin/workspace/durp/tests/../PanasonicCameraLib -I/home/constantin/workspace/durp/tests/../linux_arm_tool/include    -o CMakeFiles/test_opencl_functions.dir/src/opencl/opencl_functions/openclimagewarp.c.o   -c /home/constantin/workspace/durp/tests/src/opencl/opencl_functions/openclimagewarp.c
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/constantin/workspace/durp/tests/release_arm/CMakeFiles 16
[ 61%] Building C object CMakeFiles/test_opencl_functions.dir/src/opencl/opencl_functions/opencl_utilities.c.o
/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc-4.5   -mthumb -fdata-sections -Wa,--noexecstack -fsigned-char -Wno-psabi -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -mthumb -fdata-sections -Wa,--noexecstack -fsigned-char -Wno-psabi -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -I/home/constantin/workspace/durp/tests/../PanasonicCameraLib -I/home/constantin/workspace/durp/tests/../linux_arm_tool/include    -o CMakeFiles/test_opencl_functions.dir/src/opencl/opencl_functions/opencl_utilities.c.o   -c /home/constantin/workspace/durp/tests/src/opencl/opencl_functions/opencl_utilities.c
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/constantin/workspace/durp/tests/release_arm/CMakeFiles 17
[ 65%] Building C object CMakeFiles/test_opencl_functions.dir/src/opencl/opencl_functions/openclbackgroundsub.c.o
/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc-4.5   -mthumb -fdata-sections -Wa,--noexecstack -fsigned-char -Wno-psabi -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -mthumb -fdata-sections -Wa,--noexecstack -fsigned-char -Wno-psabi -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -I/home/constantin/workspace/durp/tests/../PanasonicCameraLib -I/home/constantin/workspace/durp/tests/../linux_arm_tool/include    -o CMakeFiles/test_opencl_functions.dir/src/opencl/opencl_functions/openclbackgroundsub.c.o   -c /home/constantin/workspace/durp/tests/src/opencl/opencl_functions/openclbackgroundsub.c
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/constantin/workspace/durp/tests/release_arm/CMakeFiles 18
[ 69%] Building C object CMakeFiles/test_opencl_functions.dir/src/opencl/opencl_functions/openclconvolution.c.o
/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc-4.5   -mthumb -fdata-sections -Wa,--noexecstack -fsigned-char -Wno-psabi -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -mthumb -fdata-sections -Wa,--noexecstack -fsigned-char -Wno-psabi -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -I/home/constantin/workspace/durp/tests/../PanasonicCameraLib -I/home/constantin/workspace/durp/tests/../linux_arm_tool/include    -o CMakeFiles/test_opencl_functions.dir/src/opencl/opencl_functions/openclconvolution.c.o   -c /home/constantin/workspace/durp/tests/src/opencl/opencl_functions/openclconvolution.c
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/constantin/workspace/durp/tests/release_arm/CMakeFiles 19
[ 73%] Building C object CMakeFiles/test_opencl_functions.dir/src/opencl/opencl_functions/openclrgbtogray.c.o
/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc-4.5   -mthumb -fdata-sections -Wa,--noexecstack -fsigned-char -Wno-psabi -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -mthumb -fdata-sections -Wa,--noexecstack -fsigned-char -Wno-psabi -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -I/home/constantin/workspace/durp/tests/../PanasonicCameraLib -I/home/constantin/workspace/durp/tests/../linux_arm_tool/include    -o CMakeFiles/test_opencl_functions.dir/src/opencl/opencl_functions/openclrgbtogray.c.o   -c /home/constantin/workspace/durp/tests/src/opencl/opencl_functions/openclrgbtogray.c
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/constantin/workspace/durp/tests/release_arm/CMakeFiles 20
[ 76%] Building C object CMakeFiles/test_opencl_functions.dir/src/opencl/test_functions.c.o
/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc-4.5   -mthumb -fdata-sections -Wa,--noexecstack -fsigned-char -Wno-psabi -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -mthumb -fdata-sections -Wa,--noexecstack -fsigned-char -Wno-psabi -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -I/home/constantin/workspace/durp/tests/../PanasonicCameraLib -I/home/constantin/workspace/durp/tests/../linux_arm_tool/include    -o CMakeFiles/test_opencl_functions.dir/src/opencl/test_functions.c.o   -c /home/constantin/workspace/durp/tests/src/opencl/test_functions.c
Linking C executable test_opencl_functions
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/test_opencl_functions.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc-4.5   -mthumb -fdata-sections -Wa,--noexecstack -fsigned-char -Wno-psabi -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -mthumb -fdata-sections -Wa,--noexecstack -fsigned-char -Wno-psabi -mfpu=vfpv3-d16  -Wl,--fix-cortex-a8 -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,--fix-cortex-a8 -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,-z,nocopyreloc -Wl,-rpath-link,/home/constantin/workspace/durp/tests/../linux_arm_tool/lib,-rpath-link,/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/lib,-rpath-link CMakeFiles/test_opencl_functions.dir/src/opencl/opencl_functions/openclpyramid.c.o CMakeFiles/test_opencl_functions.dir/src/opencl/opencl_functions/openclimagewarp.c.o CMakeFiles/test_opencl_functions.dir/src/opencl/opencl_functions/opencl_utilities.c.o CMakeFiles/test_opencl_functions.dir/src/opencl/opencl_functions/openclbackgroundsub.c.o CMakeFiles/test_opencl_functions.dir/src/opencl/opencl_functions/openclconvolution.c.o CMakeFiles/test_opencl_functions.dir/src/opencl/opencl_functions/openclrgbtogray.c.o CMakeFiles/test_opencl_functions.dir/src/opencl/test_functions.c.o  -o test_opencl_functions  -L/home/constantin/workspace/durp/tests/../linux_arm_tool/lib  -L/home/constantin/workspace/durp/CarmaDev/cuda/lib -rdynamic -lPanasonicCameraLib -lm -lOpenCL -lGAL 
CMakeFiles/test_opencl_functions.dir/src/opencl/test_functions.c.o: In function `TestPyramid':
test_functions.c:(.text+0x89c): undefined reference to `opencl_pyramid'
```

Comment: My first suspicion is that you're not recompiling cleanly.  Can you post the **exact** output of Make, after a clean?  (And ideally, simplify the test-case so that we don't have to consider 6 files here!)

Comment: Oli, I did a rm -rf *, and reran my cmake. With a fresh make it is the same. I just transferred to another computer (note I am using an arm cross compiler for the above) and a local compile (gnu gcc) worked just fine. I will try to get you the make output, I cannot share all the detail though.

Comment: Is build order a possibility? I notice the `openclpyramid.c.o` and `openclwarpimage.c.o` are linked before `opencl_utilities.c.o` and both rely on it. However... if I add both object files but do not call `opencl_pyramid` I can successfully link `openclwarpimage.c.o` regardless of order...

Comment: The fact this compiles with no problem on another computer really irks me.

Comment: Is his is cross compilation to ARM or are you running the toolchain natively? An is the other computer you mention also compiling natively? Are the compiler versions the same?

Comment: try to add and extern in test_functions.c for "opencl_pyramid" and make clean the code base

Comment: @talonmies It compiles fine natively (x86_64) on another machine. On my current machine (a host x86_64 for a target ARM), I am cross compiling.

Comment: @Chanakya.sun I cannot use extern "C" as that is undefined in gcc.

Comment: @Constantin the only thing is add a header file with the undefined and add it to the file. which compiler you are using gnu or arm version??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was classic PEBCAK. If you look really closely at the compile line, there's an `rplink-path` with no path following it. I guess the gcc linker appended the next object file as the argument to `rplink-path`.